# Date range storing in database

Tags: java, angularjs, html, mongodb

I am trying to store the daterange value in database using mongodb so I used String return type but I am not able to save the daterange . Is it posiible to save the daterange directly in the database or I have to split the daterange as start date and end date and store in the database? Frontend is AngularJS and backend is mongoDB...

Comment: Can you explain your issue a bit more.. Like things you have tried and e.g. values you try to store and exact error you get while storing??

Comment: Hi Viraj, I am not getting any error.. I tried    'private String dateRange;' and then getters and setters in entity class... from the ui I am passing value as    ng-model = "dateRange". I am not able to save in the database.I am choosing the date range from the daterange picker calendar.

Comment: did you try to log and check if the date is received in java class..? You are still sounding abstract could be better to see some code so taht we dont ask so many questions..

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB does not provide any kind of DateRange data type.

Java8 provides `Period` and `Duration` types. Before Java8 there's the great `Joda Time` library that also provides Period and Duration data types.

The MongoDB library for Java, does not have any sort of converter for those types. It only knows `java.util.Data`.

Though, if you want to store a Java8 or Joda `Period` or `Duration`, you need to either write a customer data type converter for the Java MongoDB Driver, or you do the conversion directly in your application code. (Both would be pretty much the same).

This way you can save a date range as `{ range: {from: ISODate("2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"), to: ISODate("2015-01-02T00:00:00.000Z") } }` in MongoDB.

Then of course you have to do your queries on the `range.from` and `range.to` fields.

---

The second part of course is, that the value from the HTML Date Range Picker get's serialized properly to String and can be read by your Java backend.

Though make sure (e.g. by simply using a `System.out.println(...)` ) that the data was correctly deserialized by Java.

If that all works you can deal with MongoDB, i.e. converting a DateRange object to two `java.util.Date` objects, etc. pp.